# Cannot render the next item of the ListView in DetailActivity

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I'm very new to android and trying to make a simple dictionary. So that when user clicks on a word (list item), the details (word+definition) opens using a DetailActivity. The problem is that I can not make the DetailActivity to be refreshed with the next word, when the `Next` button is clicked.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mEditTextWord;
    EditText mEditTextDefinition;
    DictionaryDatabase mDB;
    ListView mListView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mDB = new DictionaryDatabase(this);
        mEditTextWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextWord);
        mEditTextDefinition = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDefinition);
        Button buttonAddUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAddUpdate);

        buttonAddUpdate.setOnClickListener(
                new  View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        saveRecord();
                    }
                });


        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
                    view, int position, long id) {
                String nextId = String.valueOf(id+1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key" ,mDB.getWord(id)+"");
                intent.putExtra("value",mDB.getDefinition(id)+"");
                intent.putExtra("nextId",nextId+"");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Records deleted = " + mDB.deleteRecord(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                updateWordList();
                return true;
            }
        });
        updateWordList();

    }
...
```

and DetailActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button shareBtn ;
    Button nextBtn ;
    DictionaryDatabase mDB;
    TextView title, body; //Globally Declaration
    String nextId;
    int id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        try{
            String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
            String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
            String idString = getIntent().getStringExtra("nextId");
            id = Integer.parseInt(idString) + 1;  //to be used to render the next item


            title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(key);

            body = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.body);
            body.setText(value);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //render the next item. There is no error without this part
        mDB = new DictionaryDatabase(this);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String key = mDB.getWord(id);
                String value = mDB.getDefinition(id);

                title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setText(key);

                body = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.body);
                body.setText(value);
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

Runtime error:

```
com.example.dict1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.dict1, PID: 22547
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dict1/com.example.dict1.DetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I'm stock on this for hours, so appreciate your hints to resolve it.

Update: layout of the detail page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.dictshop.dict1.DetailActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="txtBody"
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Share"
        android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:onClick="shareThis"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next"
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/shareBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="nextWord"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout of the main page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.dictshop.dict1.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And DictionaryDatabse.java

```
package com.dict1shop.dict1;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by me on 19/05/16.
 */
public class DictionaryDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dict1.db";
    private static final String TABLE_DICTIONARY = "dictionary";
    private static final String FIELD_WORD = "word";
    private static final String FIELD_DEFINITION = "definition";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                "(_id integer PRIMARY KEY," +
                FIELD_WORD + " TEXT, " +
                FIELD_DEFINITION + " TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Handle database upgrade as needed
    }

    public void saveRecord(String word, String definition) {
        long id = findWordID(word);
        if (id>0) {
            updateRecord(id, word,definition);
        } else {
            addRecord(word,definition);
        }

    }

    public long addRecord(String word, String definition) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FIELD_WORD, word);
        values.put(FIELD_DEFINITION, definition);
        return db.insert(TABLE_DICTIONARY, null, values);
    }
    public int updateRecord(long id, String word, String definition) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("_id", id);
        values.put(FIELD_WORD, word);
        values.put(FIELD_DEFINITION, definition);
        return db.update(TABLE_DICTIONARY, values, "_id = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }
    public int deleteRecord(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_DICTIONARY, "_id = ?", new
                String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    public long findWordID(String word) {
        long returnVal = -1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE " + FIELD_WORD + " = ?", new String[]{word});
        Log.i("findWordID","getCount()="+cursor.getCount());
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public String getWord(long id) {
        String returnVal = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT word FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE _id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public String getDefinition(long id) {
        String returnVal = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT definition FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE _id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public Cursor getWordList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT _id, " + FIELD_WORD +
                " FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY + " ORDER BY " + FIELD_WORD +
                " ASC";
        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting a `NullPointerException` is that you never initialized your `Button nextBtn`. You declared it but you did not initialize it so the object reference is `null` right now. Before the `onClickListener()` try the following:

```
nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_of_next_Btn);
```

Let me know in the comments if you have any more questions.

Comment: I am bit confused as to what you're trying to accomplish. Can you also post the layouts so I can run your code on my terminal?

Comment: Apart from your tip, I just need to increment `id+1` at nextBtn click. And now it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i think your error is assigning `onClickListener()` method to not yet initialized button which is `nextBtn`
in `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` try to do something like this 
`nextBtn= (Buttom) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);` or whatever you called it in your xml fill 
i wish this help

Answer (score 1):

I think in your DetailActivity.class

```
nextBtn == null
```

You must do something like that:

```
Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID_HERE);
```

before

```
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you should pass your words list to `DetailActivity.java` class, So that on tap of next button, you are aware of next word that you need meaning.

Here on tap of word you are sending only that word meaning. You should pass your `arraylist` and `position` of item. So that you can fetch data from list on that particular position.

Comment: Well my goal is to make a new query based on `id +1` each time the `Next` button is tapped. Isn't it a viable approach? If not, will you kindly elaborate on how to pass the arraylist to `DetailActivity`?